# Whenever i'm Trying to install any package I'm getting "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

```
➜  ChessV  sudo apt-get -f install install-info         
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
install-info is already the newest version (6.8-4build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 187 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up install-info (6.8-4build1) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 4: /etc/environment: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried -f install a package
I even tried to reinstall the install-info package it doesn't seem to work
I'm also not able to update my ubuntu or install any other package

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin" JAVA_HOME="JAVA_HOME="/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java"
```

Comment: It says that there is something wrong with the file `/etc/environment`. Please check the contents of this file. You can copy a correct one from another working system.

Comment: can you elaborate a little more im new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of the `/etc/environment` file on my system is a single line like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
```

I am running Ubuntu 22.10.

<s>Please, check the file on your system. You are possibly missing the double quote (`"`) at the end of the line or there might be other missing or extraneous data in your file.</s>

As you see, the contents of your file contain extraneous information. The first part (starting with `PATH=`) is the same as mine. However, the rest of the line (starting with `JAVA_HOME=`) should be put on a separate line and by **removing the duplicate part (`JAVA_HOME="`)**. Your file should be something like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java"
```

However, I recommend to check whether the second line is really needed, because JAVA may not be installed on your system. Please, check with the command:

```
$ file /lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: cannot open `/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java' (No such file or directory)
```

If it says `(No such file or directory)` as in the example above, you can remove the second line completely and leave only the first line as I gave you on my first example.

---

You can edit your file with one you are familiar of the below commands:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/environment

$ gedit admin:///etc/environment

$ gnome-text-editor admin:///etc/environment
```

Comment: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"

JAVA_HOME="JAVA_HOME="/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java"                                                       this is the output of the /etc/enviornment file on my machine I'm running 22.04 I do have double quotations at the end of the path

Comment: Please edit your question and add this information into your original question ***by properly formatting it***. In this form as you posted in a comment, I cannot decide about the problem in the contents.

Comment: thank you for being so patient with me id as you asked I have put them out of the /etc/environment in the question itself

Comment: @AakashChouksey Please, check my updated answer. If it is OK, be sure to confirm by upvoting and/or clicking on the check mark. This is important for other people who may have a similar problem.

Comment: as you suggest above both the path on my system are on a separate line and I do have Java installed on my system I regularly use It too. I'm sorry to say but this might not be the solution

Comment: You said that your file contains something like `...JAVA_HOME="JAVA_HOME="...` which is wrong. Check my answer once more!

Comment: @FedKad thanks for the response sorry it was my mistake and was correct and my system is now working just fine sorry I cant upvote it I don't have 15 reputation

Comment: @AakashChouksey I Will upvote it instead ... But you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it worked for you.